# Event Handler In Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I use online converters to convert C# code to Vb.Net,but it does not properly convert event handler code.Kindly help me out.Here is my two functions:

```
     Private Sub OnPopup(sender As Object, e As PopupEventArgs)
'Piece Of Code
    End Sub

 Private Sub OnDraw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs)
 'Piece Of Code
End Sub
```

The online converters convert it as follows:

```
 Me.Popup += New PopupEventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnPopup)
        Me.Draw += New DrawToolTipEventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnDraw)
```

Kindly tell me,how to tackle this in Vb.Net

Comment: Look at the [AddHandler MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Also check [Handles Clause (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx)

Comment: This was put on hold as asking us to find a tool or off site resource. In my mind it is neither, he is asking how to convert a c# event handler to a VB.net. so I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expounding on my comment, you are looking for the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) Method.

in your case it would be

```
AddHandler Me.Draw, AddressOf OnDraw
AddHandler Me.Popup, AddressOf OnPopup
```

or you can just use `Handles` which is what the designer uses like @bansi stated.

```
Private Sub OnPopup(sender As Object, e As PopupEventArgs) Handles Me.Popup
    'Piece Of Code
End Sub

Private Sub OnDraw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) Handles Me.Draw
    'Piece Of Code
End Sub
```